# Hindu god and goddess

Tags: gods

Why in one religion there are so many gods? I am a hindu and I always get confused when my grandmother says that don't do certain things or these certain gods will punish you. Why people believe that every certain things have there own individual god? Are all those god are same and have different names or they are different from each other? Why people say lord sankar and lord shiv are different?

Comment: So I heard this somewhere and stole it - Eskimoes are aware of 300 types of snow (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eskimo_words_for_snow). Does not mean that these types exist only for them. It means they are more intimately aware of and have studied snow  in greater detail than others. Similarly, Hindus are aware of and have discovered all these gods and goddesses. They did not invent them and these gods and goddesses apply to all human beings, not just Hindus.

Comment: "Why people believe that every certain things have there own individual god?"  = Do you have different departments in the government and different leaders of each department and various levels of hierarchy? Why can't there be many gods each with their own portfolio for keeping the world safe? "Are all those god are same and have different names or they are different from each other?"  - If we are talking of gods, they are different. But have their origins in the same paramatma. "Why people say lord sankar and lord shiv are different?" - Who says this?

Comment: People around me usually say it that shiv sankar are different

Comment: They are the same.